# Escape HTML text

Tags: html, file-io, livecode

I am writing html files from a stack. This is a bit of a pain because for every line I have to write something like the following if the file contains quotes.

```
 write "<div id=hidden-" & quote & myKanton & quote && "style=" & quote & "display:block;" &quote&&"class=" &quote & "popuptable" &quote& ">" & LF to file tOutputFileCH
```

Now I have to add a lot of html code again and I'm wondering if there is an easier way to be able to do something like:

```
write escaped("my html numbers and "txt" with quotes") to file
```

I do not need variables within the html text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often, people use functions like

```
function q theText
  replace "'" with quote in theText
  return theText
end q
```

which can be used as

```
write q("<div id=hidden-'" & myKanton & "' style='display:block;'" & "class='popuptable'>" & LF) to file tOutputFileCH
```

You can use a string like in above example but you can also use any container:

```
get q(myVariable)
put q(it) into field 1
put q(field 1) into field 2
put q(url myUrl) into url myOtherUrl
put q(the cProperty of me) into myVar
-- etc etc etc
```

You can also use ´ or ` instead of ' if you change the q function.

By the way, I noticed that you don't include `hidden-` in the quotes. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: Thanks, I can try that. How would you fill in `theText` then? Does it have to be from a field on a resource stack or does it work on stack as well?  

Thanks, I also noticed the hidden-bug and already corrected it in the code :-)

Comment: It works with any data, it doesn't matter where it comes from. I'll add some examples in my answer. (Don't forget to click Accept and vote for all useful answers please).

Comment: Be careful if your data contains both single and double quotes!  :D

Comment: @splash32 Hence my tip to use other characters, such as curly single quotes, instead of the single quote.

Answer (score 0):

HTML allows use of quotes and single quotes, so you can...

```
put "<div style='border:1px'>" into tHTML
```

LiveCode's format command allows you to escape double quotes...

```
put format("my html numbers and \"txt\" with quotes") into tData
```

Comment: Format is nice, but you still need to type extra backslashes. Using the q() function is shorter, but evidently format() is still much better then writing all quotes separately.

Answer (score 0):

It is working now. I put the html lines in a custom stack property and use that as input when writing the file. Works perfectly. It even seems to work without the q function.

```
  write ( the cMapOverlay of stack "AfaConverter" ) & LF to file tOutputFileCH
```

I also tried that because

```
onmouseover="nhpup.popup($('#hidden-VS').html(), {'width': 400});" href="./kantone/index_kanton_VS.html"
```

this is trouble with q without adaptions because ' is replaced with " which is a problem.

Comment: it's common to have both single and double quotes with HTML/javascript - you're code snippet is a good example  :)

Comment: I guess.. but that makes it even more important to have some nice function, because `"target=" & quote & "_blank"` doesn't look very easy.. and that is just a small bit

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers here. Let me suggest another approach. You could use a quoting function, but in a slightly different way:

```
function q pString
  return quote & pString & quote
end q
```

Then use the LiveCode merge() function. Merge evaluates any LiveCode expression or variable enclosed in [[ ]] and incorporates it into the enclosing quoted text:

```
write merge("my html numbers and [[q("txt")]]") to file
```